# Can Cordova 'FileWriter' create/download a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, cordova, jspdf, downloadify

I've written a web application to create and download a pdf document on client-side using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and [Downloadify](http://raldenhoven.github.io/downloadify/). jsPDF prepares the document and Downloadify downloads it as a pdf. Everything works fine.

I'm trying to replicate this behavior on a PhoneGap app (using FileWriter instead of Downloadify). [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) handles writing onto files. Using FileWriter, I've created txt files but couldn't create a pdf.

1. Is is possible to create a PDF document using Cardova at all?
2. If not are there any plugins around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As of now (Cordova 2.8.0), I have concluded that there's no inbuilt API or plugins to create a pdf document usgin Cordova. I ended up creating PDF in server side using PHP plugin called [tcpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/) and downloading it in local file system.
2. Again, as of now no. But to view pdf on local file system, there's [FileOpener-Plugin](https://github.com/don/FileOpener)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create PDF file using specific ( with  Cordova support ) dll from the Apitron PDF kit package.